# Python if statements not running though

Tags: python, python-3.x

When running this just press one until you reach enter units of measurements that is all that needs to be fixed as I want to do the rest myself. Anyway when you press one it runs through all of the `elif` statements bellow it. I only need it so that it wont run through all of the `if` statements, I do not know if it is something to do with my layout but I would very much like some help thanks.

```
file.write(Ingredients)
IngredientA = input("What is the ingredient in this recipie: ")
file.write("Ingredients: \n")
file.write(IngredientA)
file.write("\n")
NumA = input("1. Grams \n 2. Milliliters\n 3.Litres\n 4.Slices\n 5.No specific measurement\n What units of measurement are used for this ingredient (1-5): ")
if NumA == 1:
    file.write("Grams")
    Amount = input("How much of this ingredient in grams does the respie contain: ")
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("Amount of ingredient:\n")
    file.write(Amount)
    file.write("\n")
    Amount = input("How much of this ingredient in Milliliters does the recipie contain: ")
elif NumA == 3:
    file.write("Litres")
    Amount = input("How much of this ingredient in Litres does the recipie contain: ")
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("Amount of ingredient:\n")
    file.write(Amount)
    file.write("\n")
elif NumA == 4:
    Amount = input("How Many slices of this ingredient does the recipie contain: ")
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("Amount of ingredient:\n")
    file.write(Amount)
    file.write("\n")
elif NumA == 5:
    file.write("No specific unit of measurement\n")
    Amount = input("How much of this ingrediant does the recipie contain: ")
    file.write("Amount of ingredient:\n")
    file.write(Amount)
    file.write("\n")
```

Comment: I feel like you are shouting at me... could you please reformat? And to answer your question, it's probably running through all the if statements because you read in a string but then compare the string to integers.

Comment: Could you show what you expect the behavior to be (i.e. what you input & what gets printed)?

Comment: Did you try printing NumA?  What was it?  Probably not an integer, but a string.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you get back from `input` is a string. The string `"1"` will never be equal to the integer `1`. You need to convert the input value to an integer, or compare the input to strings rather than integers.

Answer (score 1):

change

`NumA = input("1. Grams \n 2. Milliliters\n 3.Litres\n 4.Slices\n 5.No specific measurement\n What units of measurement are used for this ingredient (1-5): ")`

to

`NumA = int(input("1. Grams \n 2. Milliliters\n 3.Litres\n 4.Slices\n 5.No specific measurement\n What units of measurement are used for this ingredient (1-5): "))`